# Building/Running Lua from Visual Studio

Tags: c++, lua

I'm a total noob when it comes to linking and building with Visual Studio.  I would like to integrate Lua into my C++ console application.

Can someone give a step by step on how to do this from getting the Lua dependencies from lua.org, to actually running a "Hello World from Lua" in VS, and all the steps in between.

Finding something like this online has been very difficult since most require prerequisite knowledge of building Lua and such.

Thanks :)

Comment: Guess what, it *actually* does require prerequisite knowledge of how programs are built.  Post an error message, something that helps us help you instead of you expecting us to quote random snippets from the chapters in the 50-odd chapter book.  Document your question.

Comment: Add to that that building Lua is actually simple as pie, even in VS. With no real C/C++ experience, nor any VS experience, I did exactly what you are asking a few years back. The first step you might want to take care of is learning a bit of C++, since that is the factor that is likely holding you back from doing this yourself. And even then I'd worry about the choice of messing with a scripting language library in a low-level language you do not seem to know.

Comment: Add to that that learning how programs are built by example _actually_ does work very well and the question suddenly seems valid. Nothing is worse than googling for help, just to find answers like "use google". Thats like a recursive function with no exit condition.

Answer (score 3):

Start with the [Lua for Windows](http://code.google.com/p/luaforwindows/) package. It will get you a self-contained batteries included Lua installation. Lua for Windows is not an official distribution, but it is well respected by the Lua user community. You can use its `lua.exe` to gain experience with the language in a Windows environment, and its rich collection of tested extension modules is also available for use.

If you add its `include` and `lib` folders to your VS project configuration, you should be able to compile and link against Lua in short order.

One possible complication is that the LfW distribution is built against VC8's C runtime library. If that becomes a problem, then you can either compile Lua yourself as part of your Solution, or get a known good DLL that matches your specific version of Visual Studio from the [Lua Binaries](http://luabinaries.sourceforge.net/) project.

Do remember that if you are using one of the distributed DLLs, it will have been compiled as C, and not C++. That means that you *must* wrap any references to the Lua include files in `extern "C" {...}` or you will have problems with linkage.

It really helps to have some experience with VS project configuration and building. In particular, experience with mixing C and C++ in a VS project is very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I heartily recommend following the advice already given about learning C and C++ and mixing the two together.  Once you have that under your belt, you may want to check out [LuaBind](http://www.rasterbar.com/products/luabind.html) or [LuaPlus](http://luaplus.org/) for connecting C++ and Lua.  You can do it manually (and you probably should, at first, to understand what's going on under the hood), but it's more efficient and cleaner, code-wise, to use one of those binding libraries.  For debugging purposes, [Decoda](http://www.unknownworlds.com/decoda) is a good choice; it can attach to processes started in VS which contain Lua code you want to check.